# Como colocar dados no flash da sessão quando for feito o redirecionamento no Silex?

Tags: php, silex

Alguns frameworks possuem um recurso chamado Session Flash, onde é possível armazenar determinado valor na sessão e que, quando o mesmo é acessado, é removido imediatamente da mesma, sendo isso útil para mostrar mensagens de erros em determinadas requisições.

Sei fazer isso em frameworks como Laravel e CakePHP, mas como eu poderia fazer isso no Silex?

Preciso armazenar um valor como flash de sessão para exibi-lo após um redirecionamento, usando o microframework Silex, mas não sei como.

Código de exemplo:

```
$app->get('/rota', function ()  use($app){

    // Quero enviar "mensagem" com o valor "Cadastrado com sucesso aqui" num flash

    return $app->redirect('/outra/rota');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com [este exemplo](https://coderwall.com/p/cv0ctq/silex-how-to-use-flash-messages), tens de [registar](https://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/1.3/providers.html) `SessionServiceProvider`:

```
$app->register(new Silex\Provider\SessionServiceProvider());
```

Depois de registares a funcionalidade já podes:

```
$app->get('/whatever', function() use($app) { 
  # Definir mensagem e nome da mensagem (example)
  $app['session']->getFlashBag()->add('example', 'Some example flash message');
  return $app->redirect('redirect-to-some-route');
});
```

E por fim se estiveres a usar sistema de template twig, para fazer o display da(s) mesma(s):

```
{% for alert in app.session.flashbag.get('example') %}
<div class="error-message">
  <div class="alert"><strong>{{ alert }}</strong></div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```